# ElasticSearch multimatch substring search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have to combine two filters to match requirements:
- a specific list of values in r.status field
- one of the multiple text fields contains the value.
Result query (with using `Nest`, but it doesn't matter) looks like:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "isActive": {
                    "value": true
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "nested": {
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "terms": {
                            "r.status": [
                              "VALUE_1",
                              "VALUE_2",
                              "VALUE_3"
                            ]
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "bool": {
                            "should": [
                              {
                                "match": {
                                  "r.g.firstName": {
                                    "type": "phrase",
                                    "query": "SUBSTRING_VALUE"
                                  }
                                }
                              },
                              {
                                "match": {
                                  "r.g.lastName": {
                                    "type": "phrase",
                                    "query": "SUBSTRING_VALUE"
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "path": "r"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Also tried with multi_match query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "isActive": {
                    "value": true
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "nested": {
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "terms": {
                            "r.status": [
                              "VALUE_1",
                              "VALUE_2",
                              "VALUE_3"
                            ]
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "multi_match": {
                            "query": "SUBSTRING_VALUE",
                            "fields": [
                              "r.g.firstName",
                              "r.g.lastName"
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "path": "r"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

`FirstName` and `LastName` are configured in index mappings as `text`:

```
"firstName": {
  "type": "text"
},
"lastName": {
  "type": "text"
}
```

Elastic gives a lot of full-text search options: `multi_match`, `phrase`, `wildcards` etc. But all of them fail in my case looking a sub-string in my text fields. (`terms` query and `isActive` one work well, I just tried to run only them).

What options do I have also or maybe where I made a mistake?

**UPD:** Combined wildcards worked for me, but such query looks ugly. Looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Maybe I cannot follow completely but since you are using the `bool.filter` returns all matching documents why do you need the `must` and `nested` clauses? Shouldn't a list of terms queries be sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

The elasticsearch way is to use [ngram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) tokenizer.

The ngram analyzer will split your terms with a sliding window. For example, the input "Hello World" will generate the following terms:

- Hel
- Hell
- Hello
- ell
- ello
- ...
- Wor
- World
- orl
- ...

You can configure the minimum and maximum size of the sliding window (in the example the minimum size is 3). Once the sub terms are generated you can use a match query an the subfield.

Another point, it is weird to use `must` within a `filter`. If you are interested in the score, you should always use `must` otherwise use `filter`. Read [this article](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html) for a good understanding.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. But I haven't understand what exactly I missed in my query so it cannot filter `text` contents. If I'm correct, database in my case have default analyzer/tokenizer for text fields. Does this part in documentation `The analysis process allows ES to search for individual words within each full text field` means that DB will try to march exact word instead of it's part (even for wildcards)? What about boolean in filter - this is not that thing I can affect somehow, I don't need for response scores, the only option for all ES queries is to filter rows by condition.